# how to implement RPC Mechanism using RabbitMQ in java

Tags: java, rpc, rabbitmq

how to implement RPC Mechanism(both producer and consumer) using RabbitMQ  in java?i am also visit official site http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#rpc but i am getting detail description about this things.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is rather unclear, could you be a bit more specific ?

Comment: Ya do you want to have and RPC layer over RabbitMQ or do you want to access the RabbitMQ remotely.

Comment: I updated my post with a sample.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#rpc

If not you can download the source for the Java API which includes sample code here. http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v2.0.0/rabbitmq-java-client-2.0.0.zip
There is an example folder in there - The code below is from HelloServer.java and HelloClient.java

**Server**

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.StringRpcServer;

public class HelloServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String hostName = (args.length > 0) ? args[0] : "localhost";
            int portNumber = (args.length > 1) ? Integer.parseInt(args[1]) : AMQP.PROTOCOL.PORT;

            ConnectionFactory connFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
            connFactory.setHost(hostName);
            connFactory.setPort(portNumber);
            Connection conn = connFactory.newConnection();
            final Channel ch = conn.createChannel();

            ch.queueDeclare("Hello", false, false, false, null);
            StringRpcServer server = new StringRpcServer(ch, "Hello") {
                    public String handleStringCall(String request) {
                        System.out.println("Got request: " + request);
                        return "Hello, " + request + "!";
                    }
                };
            server.mainloop();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Main thread caught exception: " + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.RpcClient;

public class HelloClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String request = (args.length > 0) ? args[0] : "Rabbit";
            String hostName = (args.length > 1) ? args[1] : "localhost";
            int portNumber = (args.length > 2) ? Integer.parseInt(args[2]) : AMQP.PROTOCOL.PORT;

            ConnectionFactory cfconn = new ConnectionFactory(); 
            cfconn.setHost(hostName); 
            cfconn.setPort(portNumber);
            Connection conn = cfconn.newConnection();
            Channel ch = conn.createChannel();
            RpcClient service = new RpcClient(ch, "", "Hello");

            System.out.println(service.stringCall(request));
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Main thread caught exception: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```