# RabbitMQ java client RpcClient/RpcServer example

Tags: java, client, rabbitmq

I'm new to RabbitMQ and am trying to implement an app where RpcClient and RpcServer seems to be a good fit. This is how the app works: When a request comes, it'll call RpcClient to enqueue the request and then wait for the response. On the server side, a listener would dequeue the request and process it and then enqueue using RpcServer. In theory, this should work. I also found a page on Rabbit MQ that explains how to improve the performance by using a direct reply-to.https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html. However, I could not tell how to apply this to use the com.rabbitmq.client.RpcClient and com.rabbitmq.client.RpcServer  to implement my app. Could someone shed some lights on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[com.rabbitmq.client.RpcClient](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.5.3/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.5.3/com/rabbitmq/client/RpcClient.html) and [com.rabbitmq.client.RpcServer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.5.3/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.5.3/com/rabbitmq/client/RpcServer.html) are two convenience class to implement easy the RPC pattern.

You can also implement it with the standard class.

Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665515/how-to-implement-rpc-mechanism-using-rabbitmq-in-java) and also [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html)(using standard class)

Comment: Thanks. I looked at these two classes. But I don't get how the RpcServer knows which request to pick up. When RpcClient is created, it's created with exchange, routingKey ...etc. But when RpcServer is created, it takes channel and queueName. But RpcClient does not have function that gets a queueName. And none of RpcServer methods reference RoutingKey. I'm lost. Could someone show me an example as to how it works? If I want to create a RpcClient for each of the different routingKey and start RpcServers to process based on routingKey, how do I do it? Thanks!